# Proving the Associativity of OR

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

I need help proving the following:

`(a ∨ b) ∨ c = a ∨ (b ∨ c)`

I don't want the answer... just a hint that will help me understand the process of proving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. Use the homework tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just prove it by doing all possible values of `a`, `b` and `c` = `True`, `False`? -- there are only 2^3 = 8 different cases.

Here's a start, for `a=T`, `b=F`, `c=T`

```
(a v b) v c = a ∨ (b ∨ c)
(T v F) v T = T v (F v T)
      T v T = T v T
          T = T
```

(However, this isn't really a programming question...)

Comment: Yeah, more of a math question.

Answer (score 1):

What is your axiom set?

Not knowing the set, you could build a truth table